# How to run assembled sample data

Tags: pandas

I have a pd df assembled from various samples that I randomly picked. Now, I want to run 10,000 times and get mean values for column ['MP_learning'] and ['LCC_saving'] for each row.

How should I write the code?

I tried

output=np.mean(df), but it didn't work.

```
      PC   EL  MP_Learning LCC _saving
  0   1    0     24          95
  1   1    1     35          67
  2   1    2     12          23
  3   1    3     23          45
  4   2    0     36          67
  5   2    1     74          10
  6   2    2     80          23


   np.random.seed()

   output=[]

       for i in range (10000):

           output=np.mean(df)

    output
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Do you want to get the median value for column MP_Learning 10000 times but the values of that column haven't changed, or do you want to generate random values for that column 10000 times and then get the median value, or do you want to get the median value of 10000 runs?

Comment: values in column 2 and 3 change based on sample assigned, so I want generate random values (10000 times) and then get the median value.

Answer (score 1):

For your code, you did not post the entire code. Thus, I don't know where the data come from. However, I replicated something similar and here is the solution. For you loop code though, you suppose to append to output. Use only one of those two lines in the "for" loop code, unless you need them both.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df =\
pd.DataFrame([[1,0,24,95],
              [1,1,35,67],
              [1,2,12,23],
              [1,3,23,45],
              [2,0,36,67],
              [2,1,74,10],
              [2,2,80,23]],
              columns = ["PC","EL","MP_Learning","LCC_saving"],
              index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
              ).T

output = []
for i in range (10000):
  # Use the line below to get mean for both column
    output.append(np.mean([df.loc["MP_Learning"],df.loc["LCC_saving"]]))
  # Use the line below to get mean for one column
    output.append(np.mean(df.loc["MP_Learning"])) 

print(output)
```